# Setting up Axios call in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios, redux-thunk

I'm a noob when it comes to working with Redux. I'm trying to do an API call to a NASA API with Axios (which I can do with no problem minus Redux) and store the data in Redux rather than in component state. I've watched a few tuturials on how to do this but I'm stuck.

[Here is my project](https://codesandbox.io/s/jnjon7x46v). I created the PictureOfTheDay component which should display the NASA Picture of the Day retrieved from the API.

I'm running into problems properly displaying the data and I'm confused about how to best structure the Redux files. I have created a POD reducer file, an action file (index.js), and a POD container but they aren't properly communicating with one another. I'm not sure if this is due to not structuring Redux properly or if it's an issue passing the props. The files are located in the client/src folder.

How can I set this up the correct way so that the API data displays and is stored in Redux?